# Error al guardar una foreign key en método store del controlador

Tags: php, laravel

Soy principiante en Laravel y estoy obteniendo un error haciendo lo siguiente: para crear un doctor se le debe asignar un id de especialidad. Actualmente cuento con el siguiente código:

**Doctor**

```
class Doctor extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['room', 'speciality_id'];

    public function speciality()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Speciality');
    }


    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function getRoom()
    {
        return $this->room;
    }
}
```

**DoctorController-Create**

```
public function create()
    {
        $specialities = Speciality::all();
        $selectedSpecialities = [];

        foreach ($specialities as $speciality) {
            $selectedSpecialities[$speciality->id] = $speciality->name;
        }

        return view('doctors/create')->
        with("specialities", $selectedSpecialities);
    }
```

**DoctorController-Store**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user = new User();
    $user->email = $request['email'];
    $user->password = $request['password'];
    $user->name = $request['name'];
    $user->surnames = $request['surnames'];
    $user->phone = $request['phone'];
    $user->admin = (bool) $request['admin'];
    $user->gender = $request['gender'];
    $user->save();

    $doctor = new Doctor();
    $doctor->room = $request['room'];
    $doctor->user_id = $user->id;
    $doctor->speciality_id = $request['speciality_id'];
    $doctor->save();

    return Redirect::to('doctors');
}
```

**Doctor-create.blade. Adjunto sólo la parte de especialidad**

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <label for="speciality">Especialidad</label>
  <select name="speciality_id" id="exampleInputSpeciality1" class="form-control" required autofocus>
    @foreach($specialities as $speciality)
    <option value="{{ $speciality }}">{{ $speciality }}</option>
  @endforeach
  </select>
```

El usuario se crea correctamente y al cargar el formulario de creación no se produce ningún problema. Sin embargo, al intentar guardar los datos ocurre lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que en vez de recibir el `id` de la especialidad se guarda el nombre. Sin embargo, no sé cómo solucionar este error. ¿El problema es del método create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo no convertiría en array `$specialities` y trabajaría con la colección.

**DoctorController - Create:**

```
public function create()
{
    $specialities = Speciality::all(); 
    view('doctors/create')-> 
              with(['specialities' => $specialities]);
}
```

En la vista, en lugar de poner el nombre de la especialidad en el `value` de cada `option` se pone el `id`:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <label for="speciality">Especialidad</label>
  <select name="speciality_id" id="exampleInputSpeciality1" class="form-control" required autofocus>
    @foreach($specialities as $speciality)
       <option value="{{ $speciality->id }}">{{ $speciality->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
  </select>
</div>
```

Con estos cambios te llega a la función `store` el `id` de la especialidad y no el `name`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ha solucionado el error :)